# pip list command shows tensorflow as installed, but it cannot be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I know that this is (sort of) a duplicate question, however the original has no activity and remains unanswered.

My problem is that I have installed tensorflow for python 3.7.5 and upon installation (and reinstallation, including reinstallation without cache (pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow)) it showed as successfuly installed every time. When I use the pip list command in cmd it also shows that tensorflow and all the modules it comes with are installed.

However, when I open IDLE and type 
`import tensorflow`
it gives me the ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: What version of TensorFlow did you installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a virtual environment for TensorFlow and then activate it.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this sorted my problems! I should have known to use a venv in the first place, I'm not very good at python just yet.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: @Radhikasoni, please keep up the good work and keep answering questions thank you for sharing.